# NullPointerException on TypedQuery<String> -- JavaEE Spring JPA2.1

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jpa, jpql

Java Spring (4.0.1) web app (set up in NetBeans 8.0.2). No Maven or Hibernate. EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) persistence.
Builds and Deploys okay. Getting the following in server log when running:

> StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at main.CourseDao.getAllCoursename(CourseDao.java:29)

CourseDao as follows:

```
package main;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class CourseDao {
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

public List<String> getAllCoursename() { 
   TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.coursename FROM Course AS c", String.class);
   return query.getResultList();
   }
}
```

Line 29 is

```
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.coursename FROM Course AS c", String.class);
```

So, its getting null on the database query.
But the persistence seems okay in the sense that the main objects deploy as entities: So Course.java creates a table Course in the database on deployment.

persistence.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ReportsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/reports</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Course.java as follows:

```
package main;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Course  implements Serializable {
 private int id;
 private String coursecode;
 private String coursename;

public Course() {
    }
public Course(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }
 public Course(int id, String coursecode, String coursename) {
   this.id = id;
   this.coursecode = coursecode;
   this.coursename = coursename;
    } 
@Id 
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
    }  
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }
@Column(name="COURSECODE", length=12)
public String getCoursecode() {
    return this.coursecode;
    }
public void setCoursecode(String coursecode) {
    this.coursecode = coursecode;
    }
@Column(name="COURSENAME", length=256)
public String getCoursename() {
    return this.coursename;
    }
public void setCoursename(String coursename) {
    this.coursename = coursename;
    }
}
```

COURSE table currently has only 3 rows, no null values.

applicationContext.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
    p:url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/reports"
    p:username="*******"
    p:password="*******" />
</beans>
```

I've tried all this with Hibernate rather than EclipseLink JPA2.1 - same problem is eventually encountered.

CourseDao is called by index.jsp currently (yes so this is a cheap first go; hardly best practice; but this isn't where the error is occurring):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="main.*"%>
<jsp:useBean id="courseDao" class="main.CourseDao" scope="request" />
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head> etc </head>
<body>
 <hr><ol> 
    <% for (String coursename : courseDao.getAllCoursename()) { %>
        <li> <%= coursename %> </li>
    <% } %>
    </ol><hr>
 </body>
</html>
```

All I want to do is select a column from a table with a JPQL query, and push it to the front jsp. Simple stuff. Any thoughts or assistance very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess em(Entity Manager reference object) is null. Do debug and check if em is null or not.

Comment: You're right -- its null. .. So now I'm trying to figure out why that might be so..

Comment: I gather it may have something to do with the location of the persistence.xml file. It is in "Configuration Files" directory just under the root directory (where NetBeans placed it).

Comment: The app is just a web application, not an enterprise application with WAR and EJB folders...

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a Spring Bean by `<jsp:useBean id="courseDao" class="main.CourseDao" scope="request" />` (This would create a "normal" Java Bean, but your DAO must be a Spring Bean).

You should have a look at Spring MVC (for example this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm)), so see how Spring, and JSPs work together.

Comment: Thank you. I've worked on fixing the jsp - but the problem that keeps recurring is to do with the courseDao itself rather than the jsp. For the moment I'm doing things differently with an enterprise application structure, but will likely come back to this.

Comment: @anvw: Add an default constructor to your DAO, that prints some loging statement. If this log statement occures only one time (while starting the application), then its all fine. But if the log statement occures for every request (while rendering that jsp) then the problem is still the same: you MUST use the Spring Bean and can not use `<jsp:useBean`